# Overwrite permited_params if rails controller has been inherited

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, strong-parameters, grails-controller

Here an example:

```
class Base<ApplicationController
  private

  def permited_params
    params.require(:object_name).permit(:name, :description)
  end
end

class Post<Base
  private

  def permited_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:name, :description, :owner)
  end
end
```

I'm getting an error ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError when call action create. How I can overwrite this permited_params

Comment: I do not understand what you want to overwrite? If you call the permited_params in your create action it requires :post and permits(:name etc.   If submitting other params rails usually does not throw and error but will only save the permitted params.

Comment: Your `Base` class is requiring `object_name` and the `Post` class `post` to exist. Is this just typo in your question here or did you copy paste your code?

Comment: This is not typo. The question is it possible overwrite from require(:object_name) to require(:post) in inherited controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Params, in general, have a good reason to exist and make sure that not everything can be saved into your database. However, if you want to permit all params you can call

```
params.require(:post).permit!
```

In case you just want to change the params you can change the attribute names.

```
params.require(:post).permit(:name, :description, :some_you_want, some_more ) etc.
```

In general, you should add all params you want to save into the list of permitted params. So you make sure that all the attributes you want to save will be stored and no more. You can have `permitted_params` in every controller. You do not need to call it permitted params. For instance you can call it like this in your *posts_controller*:

```
def create
  @post = Post.new(post_params)
  #.... your code
end

private 
def post_params 
  params.require(:post).permit(:name, :description, :owner)
end
```

This also works for inherited controllers.

Instead of  `params.require(:post).permit(...`
you can use whatever params you want, like `params.require(:reply).permit(...`
The required param will throw an error if it is not available. So you need to make sure it exists for example by

```
@post = Post.new
```

Other params are optional and will not cause an error by default.

Comment: But if I would like to change :post to something other? For example in parent controller it's params.require(:post).permit(...) and in child params.require(:reply).permit(...). Should it work?

Comment: Yes, you can use whatever you want for the params. If you use :reply in your reply_controller it shall work